# ¿Cómo generar esta figura en CSS?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, web

Quiero implementar un `div` con la forma que se encuentra en la siguiente imagen...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

... pero quisiera realizarlo sin necesidad de imágenes, solo *CSS*. Estuve probando con `clip-path`, pero solo se pueden realizar líneas rectas o circunferencias. Utilicé pseudoclases como `after` y `before` pero no logro conseguir la forma correcta.

¿Cómo realizar esta forma en *CSS*, sin necesidad de imágenes?

La manera que he probado de realizar esta forma ha sido:

```css
body {
  background-color: #F7F0D0;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.inverted-border-radius {
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  width: 325px;
  background-color: #F66969;
  border-radius: 25px 25px 25px 0;
}

.inverted-border-radius::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  
  background-color: transparent;
  bottom: -50px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 25px;
  border-top-left-radius: 25px;
  box-shadow: 0 -25px 0 0 #F66969;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Border inverted</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class = "inverted-border-radius"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

De esta manera consigo la curva superior derecha y la curva superior izquierda, la consigo dándole un `border-radius` en esa punta pero la inclinación aún no sé cómo hacerla. Con `clip-path`, la figura pierde el `border-radius`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes jugar con las posiciones de los contenedores que elijas, div, span, etc en absoluto y relativo colocándolos como quieras y darle un background a dichos contenedores con el color que deban tener para posteriormente darles forma con por ejemplo "border-radius" y un width y height concretos, teniendo en cuenta que comenzará por la esquina superior izquierda del objeto describiendo un moviento como el de las agujas del reloj, quedando de este modo así en este ejemplo:

```css
.forma{
    position:relative;
    top:2em;
    left:3em;
    width:5em;
    height:5em;
    border-radius: 10px 30px 15px 150px;
    background-color:#ccc;
    border:2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="forma">&nbsp;</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Pudieras intentarlo con la propiedad `clip-path` y creando un polígono de este modo:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <title>Ejemplo</title>
      <style>
        .figura-rara {
          background-color: steelblue;
          height: 200px;
          clip-path: polygon(0% 30%, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
        }
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="figura-rara">
      
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**Notas**

- Creamos con ayuda de un `div` un polígono que cumpla las siguientes reglas:

  - del extremo superior izquierdo separamos el polígono un 30%, para lograr la línea de pendiente
  - La siguiente pareja de valores nos ayudan a mantener la figura  pegada a la esquina superior derecha
  - La siguiente pareja de valores la dejamos como 100% y 0% para lograr tenga mayor altura que su extremo contrario y no despegue de la esquina inferior derecha
  - La última pareja de porcentajes ayuda mantener la figura pegada a la esquina inferior izquierda

Nota: Aún no doy con la respuesta para generar el efecto de borde de las esquinas

Comment: En mi navegador se ve todo azul, sin forma. https://imgur.com/ZbUOb2L.png

Comment: @ArtEze que navegador usas? pues este código lo probé en Google Chrome y funciona

Comment: Estoy en _Linux_, con el navegador _Luakit_, no es muy buen navegador pero es el único que anda bien en mi compu.

Comment: Lo siento no tengo el gusto de conocer dicho navegador, igual [aqui puedes revisar sobre el soporte a **`clip-path`**](https://caniuse.com/#search=clip-path)